# jquery highlight a link or remove the highlightning

Tags: jquery

There is a function in Jquery and if a user clicks on the link, the link is going to be highlighted.
I'd like my function to do :

1. If user presses a link -> highlight the link
2. If the user presses another link (un)highlight the link before and highlight the last clicked link.

Can someone help?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function() {
         $(this).css("font-weight", "bold");
     });
 });
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't u use a css class to set the highlight style?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("a").click(function() {
         $("a.highlight").removeClass("highlight");
         $(this).addClass("highlight");
     });
 });
```

**CSS**

```
.highlight{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xMyxU/

Comment: one more question: Now it's going to be highlighted but it creates a border, I'd like to just highlight it... is that possible somehow?

Comment: Is It displaying a thin dotted border? I think you're seeing an outline. You can remove this by adding outline: none; or outline: 0; to your css (either on all anchors or only on the highlight class)

Comment: The link was in a box... I did padding:0; margin: 0; solved the problem.